# How to Launch an Activity on Button click after check box

Tags: android, button, android-activity, checkbox, launch

I have got my MainActivity.java which contains 3 checkBox widgets and one Button, and I also have 3 Activities. my question is how do I assign every checkbox to launch one activity. for example : i need checkbox1 to launch Activity1, and checkbox2 to launch Activity2 ...

can someone please help ?!

thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to start activity from a CheckBox click, or from the button click?

Comment: I recommend using RadioButtons instead of CheckBoxes. If user ticks more than 1 check box, then although you launch many activities, only 1 will be visible. You won't face this problem while using RadioButtons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void onButtonClick(View view){
    if(Check whether first check box is selected) {
        Use Explicit Intents to call the activity prefered
    }
    else if(2nd check box selected){
         Use intents to call respective activity
    }
    else {
         Call the left out activity using intents
    }
}
```

I didnt want to show all code. With this basic structure, hope you can work further.

Comment: as @AGS suggested you can use radio buttons for better implementation.